# Ionic 4 Angular built-in i18n

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, internationalization

I'm developing an Ionic 4 application with Angular right now. The development language is English, but the user target is German. Usually in my web projects I'm using the built-in solution for i18n in Angular (using i18n element tags) together with [ngx-i18nsupport](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport), which works quite well.

Since Ionic 4 is using Angular's build tools and structure I went with implementing i18n tags and try to use a similar approach like in the web projects, i.e. extracting i18n tags in xlf and translate it. Extracting the files works fine and when I provide a German translation file, build it with `ng build --configuration=beta:german` and serve the result in `www` directory (Ionic default) I see a German site.

But as soon as I build the Ionic app with `ionic cordova build android --configuration=beta:german` the app is always shown in English. Even the www content is still English.

My configuration in `angular.json` looks like

```
{
  "projects": {
    "app": {
       "build": {
          .....
          "configurations": {
            "production": { ... },
            "beta:german": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.beta.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "i18nFile": "src/assets/locale/messages.de.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf",
              "i18nLocale": "de",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
       .....
       "ionic-cordova-build": {
         ....,
         "configurations": {
            "beta:german": {
              "browserTarget": "app:build:beta:german"
            }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

I know ngx-translate exists, but I want to consider it as the last option, because it requires some change in the code base.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem yet? We are running into the same issue.

Comment: @EricJeker well no. Right now we went with ngx-translate and ngx-i18nsupport tools, that offer a way to generate the json files (for ngx-translate) out of the (translated) xlf, which is quite nice. It's not perfect, but at least working. See https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/wiki/ngx-translate-usage